# Photo editing software

Tags: photo, photo-editing

I want the software to have the following features

- resize pictures
- Reduce picture quality
- change pictures format (Example png to jpg)
- Crop the photo

Most of these tasks should be done together

Sorry, my English language is faint

Comment: If you're using Arch Linux, please note that this site offers support only for [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours). Questions about Arch Linux maybe welcome at https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu forum.
Please ask the official forum :  https://bbs.archlinux.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a Q&A site specific to Ubuntu, if you don't get the answers you need here, it might be best to try asking at the [Unix and Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Regardless, [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) can do all of those tasks, and although I've never tried it in Arch i'm sure it's possible: https://www.gimp.org/downloads/